# Latitude specifications: in $45^{\circ} 23' N$, what does the $23'$ represent?

Tags: geometry, notation, terminology, unit-of-measure

When the latitude of a location on Earth is specified I notice that there are two numbers. For instance a latitude could be given as $45^{\circ} 23' N$ I understand that the $45^{\circ}$ is the elevation from the equator towards the North Pole, but in the simplest terms possible, what does the $23'$ represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $23'$ represents [arcminutes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc) (angular minutes). One arcminute is ${1\over60}$ of one degree.

So $45^\circ23'$ is the same as $45{23\over60}$ degrees, which is about $45.383^\circ$.